# My winform button spawns checkboxes when pressed, how can I let code run when one is checked?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, checkbox

```
    private void NewNoiseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonList.Add(new CheckBox());
        int buttonNumber = buttonList.Count - 1;

        buttonList[buttonNumber].Location = new Point(2, buttonList.Count * 30 - 30);
        allNoisePanel.Controls.Add(buttonList[buttonNumber]);
    }

    private void checkboxIsChecked(CheckBox checkBox)
    {
        //How do I make this code run?
    }

    private void checkboxIsUnchecked(CheckBox checkBox)
    {
        //How do I make this code run?
    }
```

Whenever the 'NewNoiseButton' is checked, I want the void checkBoxIsChecked to run, but since the buttons are created through code, I found this very difficult to do.

Comment: Do you mean you want to assign that event to programatically created controls or just `checkboxIsChecked(buttonList.Last())`?

Comment: If you have button to control checkbox, then probably you don't need button. Just click on checkbox

Comment: @Sayse correct, the code should create a list of buttons.

Comment: User, thats not what I said in my initial comment, your code does create a list of buttons already, but what is it you are trying to do now? assign an event to the new checkboxes or just call the method?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you can use the following approach:

```
List<CheckBox> buttonList = new List<CheckBox>();
void NewNoiseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var cb = new CheckBox();
    buttonList.Add(cb);

    cb.Location = new Point(2, buttonList.Count * 30 - 30);
    allNoisePanel.Controls.Add(cb);
    cb.CheckedChanged += cb_CheckedChanged;
}
void cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
    if(cb.Checked)
        checkboxIsChecked(cb);
    else
        checkboxIsUnchecked(cb);
}
void checkboxIsChecked(CheckBox checkBox) {
    //How do I make this code run?
}
void checkboxIsUnchecked(CheckBox checkBox) {
    //How do I make this code run?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this:

```
private void NewNoiseButton_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
  CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
  buttonList.Add( checkBox );
  int buttonNumber = buttonList.Count - 1;
  checkBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler( CheckBoxCheckedChanged );

  buttonList[ buttonNumber ].Location = new Point( 2, buttonList.Count * 30 - 30 );
  allNoisePanel.Controls.Add( buttonList[ buttonNumber ] );
}

void CheckBoxCheckedChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
  CheckBox checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
  if (checkBox!=null)
  {
    if (checkBox.Checked)
    {
      // do something
    }
    else
    {
      // do something else
    }
  }
}
```